# Android: Destroyed my app while trying to change the name. Any chance to restore it?

Tags: android, android-studio

i tried to change my apps name according to a tutorial but something went wrong and now even the folder where the project was stored, is empty. Only the ".idea" folder is left.
Any chance to restore my project? There isnt even anything left i could open in Android studio.

Comment: look at Recycle Bin ?

Comment: Theres nothing in it. Android Studio just overwrote the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to download a un-delete program.

Link : [undelete360](http://www.undelete360.com)

I had used this program and worked for me :)